# infranilmanifolds: harmonic forms parallel?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, nilpotent-groups

I am studying Lott's paper : "On the spectrum of a finite volume negatively-curved manifold" and the satement is following:

We have an compact infranilmanifold $N$ which is finitely covered by a nilmanifold $ \tilde{N} / \Gamma $ and endowed with a leftinvariant metric. On $N$ we have therefore a flat connection $\nabla$, such that all leftinvariant vectorfields on $N$ are parallel.
Now it is said, that all harmonic forms on $N$ are parallel.

Why is this the case? It is clear, that every parallel form is harmonic, but why also the other direction?

Here is the link:
[Lott: On the spectrum of a fintie volume negatively-curved manifold](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-math9908136)
It's in the proof of Theorem 1.

Comment: It is good form to say *which* paper you are studying and, if possible, to include a link.  This usually attracts more responses.